# How to change the ugly cursor image on disabled radio buttons / checkboxes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, disabled-control

I want to remove this ugly red image on hover on disabled controls which appears in most browsers (Chrome, Internet Explorer etc.)

[image]

Comment: In case of other options, except for the answer below in CSS3 context, please add answers

Comment: just in case -> FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If CSS3 is an option, simply use the :disabled selector and set the cursor to something else:

```
input[type='radio']:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}

input[type='checkbox']:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

**CSS**

For `radio` button in disable state

```
input[type='radio']:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

For `checkbox` in disable state

```
input[type='checkbox']:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* goodby the ugly cursor image on disabled inputs */
input:disabled {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```